# double.ToString(???) - format to drop digits BEFORE decimal point and show 2 digits AFTER decimal point?

Tags: c#, formatting, precision

Is it possible to dislay only the cents in an amount using *only* ToString(), something like 1.99.ToString("SOME FORMAT HERE")?

e.g. what if I want 1.99 to be displayed as "1 dollar(s) 99 cents"

`($"{ Convert.ToInt32(amount) } dollar(s) { amount.ToString("???") } cents")`?

Comment: No you would need to override ToString to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

This would work if amount is a double. If amount is string then you wouldn't need ToString() in following line. Note this is assuming a format you listed in your question:

```
string line = string.Concat("$", amount.ToString().Split('.')[0], " dollar(s) ", amount.ToString().Split('.')[1].Substring(0,2), " cents");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this with only the `ToString` method, so here's another way.

You can first get the decimal part by doing this:

```
var decimalPart = yourDouble - (int)yourDouble;
```

Then, you can times the decimal part by 100 and convert the result to an int.

```
var twoDigits = (int)(decimalPart * 100);
```

To convert this to a two digit string, you just pad 0s to the left:

```
var result = twoDigits.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not do this using only ToString(), but this is almost what you want :)

```cs
double d = 15.12;
var str = d.ToString("0 dollar(s) .00 cents").Replace(".", string.Empty);
```

Anyway, I suggest you to create an extension method to do this:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToFormattedString(this double number)
    {
        var integerPart = Convert.ToInt32(number);
        var decimalPart = Convert.ToInt32((number - integerPart) * 100);
        return String.Format("{0} dollar(s) {1} cents", integerPart, decimalPart);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToFormattedString());
```